# Getting data from a Barcode Scanner using PHP

Tags: php, barcode-scanner

I've read a couple of posts here on the site and as far as I understand it, using PHP to get and process the information obtained through a Barcode Scanner is possible, however I'd like to ask just to make sure, is it recommended? are there any caveats I should be aware of?

**EDIT**
I don't know the software of the barcode scanner since I haven't had access to it, however I described how it works on the comments down here. the barcode generates a fixed number of characters so I guess I could use a javascript event listener =)

Comment: Where is the scanner running, on the client or on the server?

Comment: There are 2 scanners that will be used for what I intent to build, one that plugs directly via USB (to the computer running the service) and another that stores them on an internal memory then also plugs via USB

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed a lot of stores use online or LAN POS sites to handle purchases. Typically, the add an item page will set focus to a text field devoted to the product's barcode. When the scanner scans the barcode it's been preconfigured to output the code to wherever the cursor is (in this case, the barcode text field). Most system then have a JavaScript event listener on the field that submits the new item when a barcode is entered (the field reaches a certain length). Of course this is all theory. If you want sample code, please provide more specifics on the scanner and the software it came with.